# Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a' despite declaring RouterModule in app.module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a template parse error when using ***[routerlink]*** in html page,whereas I imported RouterModule. Please take a look in the below HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <h3 [style.color]="white">ADMIN PORTAL</h3>
  <span class="spacer-left"></span>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="islogged"> View Book Lists </button>
  <a mat-button *ngIf="islogged" [routerlink]="['/addNewBook']"> Add a Book </a>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="islogged" (click)="logout()"> Logout </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Notice that I'm using angular material design.

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import 'hammerjs';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';
import { AddNewBookComponent } from './components/add-new-book/add-new-book.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AddNewBookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [LoginService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please note I imported RouterModule implicitly via ***routing*** variable which is exported in below separated TypeScript file:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/components/login/login.component';
import { AddNewBookComponent } from '../app/components/add-new-book/add-new-book.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'addNewBook',
    component: AddNewBookComponent
  }
]
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Even if I imported RouterModule in the above file, I still facing this detailed error in browser as below:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerlink'
since it isn't a known property of 'a'. (">   <button mat-button
*ngIf="islogged"> View Book Lists </button>   <a mat-button *ngIf="islogged" [ERROR ->][routerlink]="['/addNewBook']"> Add a Book </a>   <button mat-button *ngIf="islogged" (click)="logout"):
ng:///AppModule/NavbarComponent.html@4:33
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
(compiler.js:14830)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
(compiler.js:24018)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
(compiler.js:24005)
    at compiler.js:23948
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
(compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
(compiler.js:23857) syntaxError @ compiler.js:1021
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
@ compiler.js:14830
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
@ compiler.js:24018
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
@ compiler.js:24005 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:23948
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
@ compiler.js:23948 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:23858 then @
compiler.js:1012
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
@ compiler.js:23857
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
@ compiler.js:23817
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync
@ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule
@ core.js:4352 ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78 0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32 (anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

I'm tankful for any help. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write routerLink with 'L' upper-case not 'routerlink'

also, you should separate the app.routing file as SiddAjmera shown.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anywhere you have imported RouterModule in app.module.ts. you need to import RouterModule.

**EDIT**

You need to make the routes into a module as follows,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { };
```

and import the **`AppRoutingModule`**  into **`app.module.ts`**

Answer (score 1):

A correct way of doing it would be to create a module

```
...
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
...

const appRoutes: Routes = [...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And then add `AppRoutingModule` to the `imports` array of your `AppModule`:

```
...
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now since you've exported the `RouterModule` from the `AppRoutingModule` you will have access to everything that is exported by the `RouterModule` in the `AppModule`

Another thing is it's not `routerlink` it's `routerLink`(in Camel Case)

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags only need property binding, not square-bracket.

> The navigation paths are fixed, so you can assign a string to the routerLink (a "one-time" binding).

[Router docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)